How to show any function from $A$ to $B$ is not onto?
I was reading the book A Course on Borel sets by S.M. Srivastava, and there was a theroem essentially stating the Cardinality of a set is strictly less than of it's Power set.
Now in that proof we had to show that there doesn't exist any onto function from $X$ to $\mathcal P(X)$ (the power set of $X$) which will complete the proof and they did that without using anything about the Codomain being a power set
My question is can we prove for a set $A$ and $B$ there doesn't exist any onto function from $A$ to $B$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Their proof almost certainly used that the codomain is a power set, since that's precisely what they're trying to prove.

For instance, when they say "suppose $A=f(x_0)$" they assume that the codomain is the power set, else $A$ (being a subset of $X$) makes no sense as an output of $f$.

What is $A,B?$ Let $A\neq \emptyset$ any set, $B:=A$ there is an onto function. But i am sure that is not what you mean.

"they did that without using anything about the Codomain being a power set", from what I checked they very much did use that

@Tina Also let $A=\emptyset$ and $B:=A$, there is an onto function.

In general, to show a function $f \colon A \to B$ is not surjective, it suffices to find an element $b \in B$ such that for all $a \in A$, $f(a) \neq b$.
In particular, given $f \colon X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$, let $$ B = \left\{ x \in X \mid x \notin f(x) \right\} $$
Observe that $B$ is a subset of $X$, which means it's an element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. We claim $f(x) \neq B$ for all $x \in X$.
Consider $x \in X$. Since $f(x)$ is a subset of $X$, either $x \in f(x)$ or not. Consider the cases:

If $x \in f(x)$, then $x \notin B$. This means $f(x) \neq B$, because one of the sets contains $x$ and the other does not.
If $x \notin f(x)$, then $x \in B$. This means $f(x) \neq B$, because one of the sets contains $x$ and the other does not.

Either way, we have $f(x) \neq B$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $f$ cannot be surjective.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to PSQs &  dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
